# How to View saved files in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi i created one sample application that saves data as text file using simple c (FILE) function . I am using below code

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Log.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp,"%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t\n","Id","Type","MacId","IPAddress","Version");
fclose(fp);
```

When i run this code in simulator.There is a Log.txt file in Macintosh HD folder.Then i can able to view the text file log.When i run this in device ,Where it can store .txt file and how can i view this text file ? Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the file to the documents-directory.

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Log.txt"];
```

edit:

```
FILE *fp = fopen([fullPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "w");
```

Comment: After doing this, use the Xcode Organizer to download the contents of the app's document folder from the device.

Comment: This line crashes fprintf(fp,"%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t\n","Id","Type","MacId","IPAddress","Version");
my application

Comment: did you convert fullPath to a CString before you used fopen?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by fluchtpunkt, Documents directory is the place where you can put your files. Simplest way to do it is perhaps creating NSString instance and then call **writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:** method. Check NSString documentation for details.